# How to setup a username and password for a database?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When I create a database in pgadmin, it never asks me username/password for that database.

How do I define a database with such credentials:

- DBName: mydb
- username: phil
- password: pass123

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't use ORACLE's logic, so a database hasn't 1:1 relation to a user. If you're creating a database, choose the DB owner. By default the DB owner is the current signed in user.

After creating a database, you can grant or revoke access rights, including changing DB owner.

If you want to create a new user, you have to separate it into two steps:

1. create a user
2. create a database with the user as a DB owner